# how to get the first image from another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a page (www.domain.co.uk/index.html) where I need to get the url of an image from another page (www.domain.co.uk/photos.html)

inside `www.domain.co.uk/photos.html` I have a load of photos.

example of the images; where `foo`, `bar`, `baz` and `qux` are completely different strings :

```
<tr>
<th width="697" scope="col">
<div id="qux">
<a href="foo" target="_blank"><img src="bar.jpg" alt="" width="700" height="525" class="baz"></a>
</div>
</th>
</tr>
```

How can I pin point one and get the url for `www.domain.co.uk/index.html` using javascript?

---

Could I add a class `photo` that is the same for every image like this:

```
<tr>
<th width="697" scope="col">
<div id="qux">
<a href="foo" target="_blank"><img src="bar.jpg" alt="" width="700" height="525" class="baz photo"></a>
</div>
</th>
</tr>
```

And then link to the class `.photo` and retrieve that from the url `www.domain.co.uk/photos.html`

---

I know how to do it with the current url.

```
$('.photo').attr('href')
```

But how do you perform that on another url?

Comment: You can make an ajax call to this page an select the first image link with some javascript but it's heavy for just an img link

Comment: Not clear .. do you want to show image from photo.html page to index or something else ?

Comment: Would you use jQuery for that? That could be done in a breeze with it.

Comment: @blint but it is on a different page

Comment: I think a better way to go would be to change index.html and photos.html so they get their image sources from one common place, whether it's a script file (.js), a JSON file (.json), or ideally, a database, service, or *anything* server-side; that's up to you. What you're proposing to do is inefficient and just plain *bad*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me.

The alert box reads: `http://localhost/enhzflep/img/catSource.jpg`

**Excerpt from imageThreshold.html**

```
<body>
    <img id='srcImg' src='img/catSource.jpg'/> <input type='range' min='0' max='255' id='thresholdSlider'/><span id='sliderVal'>128</span>
    <canvas id='dstCanvas'></canvas>
</body>
```

**Excerpt from test.html**

```
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
    myAjaxRequest("http://localhost/enhzflep/imageThreshold.html", onHtmlLoaded);
}

function onHtmlLoaded(ajax)
{
    var div = newEl('div');
    div.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
    var imgs = div.getElementsByTagName('img');
    alert(imgs[0].src);
}


function myAjaxRequest(url, callback)
{
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
            callback(this);
    }
    ajax.onerror = function()
    {
        console.log("AJAX request failed to: " + url);
    }
    ajax.open("GET", url, true);
    ajax.send();
}
```

Comment: I just kept changing the number in `alert(imgs[0].src);` to find the correct image

Comment: I am getting the error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Then you need to either (a) request a resource from the same origin or (b) set the header such that it allows cross-origin requests. In the case of content delivery networks (CDNs) anyone can generally request a resource from there with a script on their own server. But, if you have a page running at example.com and you want a page from example2.com, it wont work unless example2.com sets the right field in the header. A google for "No 'Access-Control-Allow' header" should give you much more knowledge and insight than I could ever do. There's many Qs here at SO that deal with the issue too. :)

Answer (score 1):

This will get the first image's src:

```
$(pagehtml).find('img').first().attr('src');
```

This will get you the first image's link if any, and error if it doesn't have a link:

```
var t = $(pagehtml).find('img').first().closest('a');
if(!t.length)
    console.error('first image does not have a link')
else
    alert(t.attr('href')); // first image's link
```

This will get you the first image that has the link, skipping any images that doesn't have a link:

```
var t = $(pagehtml).find('a[href] img').first();
if(!t.length)
    console.error('there\'s no image with a link in this page');
else
    alert(t.closest('a').attr('href'));
```

`$(pagehtml)` should contain the parsed HTML code from your target page. To get that use:

```
$.ajax({ url:'photos.html', complete:function(r){ 

    var pagehtml = r.respnseText;
    $(pagehtml).find('...'); 
    // ...

 } });
```

Answer (score 0):

sessionstorage:

using sessionstorage with jquery you can save a parameter and use it later in any page.

```
 var img = $('.photo').attr('src')
 sessionStorage.setItem("imgurl", img);
```

and to take the saved info in any page

```
 var x = sessionStorage.getItem("imgurl");
 $('.photo').attr('src',x);
```